# java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points

Tags: java, excepciones

Estaba intentando leer unos datos a través de un servidor, al principio bien:

```
Datagrama recibido del host: /10.166.122.105 desde el puerto remoto: 37547
x=-0.077811554 y=0.094570965 z=9.7324295 grados=0.0
Datagrama recibido del host: /10.166.122.105 desde el puerto remoto: 37547
x=-0.08379706 y=0.09696517 z=9.716867 grados=0.0
...
Datagrama recibido del host: /10.166.122.105 desde el puerto remoto: 37547
x=-0.07182605 y=0.09935937 z=9.701305 grados=0.0.0
```

Así unas cuantas líneas, hasta que de repente me ha aparecido este mensaje:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at paquete.Servidor.main(Servidor.java:62)
```

He buscado en internet y no me queda bastante claro la razón de esa excepción (ya que toda la información está en inglés) ¿Alguien podría explicarme la razón por favor? Un saludo

PD: He probado a usar la clase DecimalFormat, ya que pensaba que podía ser debido a que coge muchos decimales pero sigue sin funcionar

Código completo

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    try {
    DatagramSocket socketUDP = new DatagramSocket(puerto);  
    System.out.println("Servidor iniciado");    
    System.out.println("En espera de cliente..."); 

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

    //Para pasar el byte de String a double
    double x, y, z, grados;
    String xS, yS, zS, gradosS;
    boolean continuar=true;


    while(true) {

            DatagramPacket datosCliente = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);


            socketUDP.receive(datosCliente);

            System.out.print("Datagrama recibido del host: " + datosCliente.getAddress());
            System.out.println(" desde el puerto remoto: " +datosCliente.getPort());

          contiene el Datagram recibido
            DatagramPacket respuesta = new DatagramPacket(datosCliente.getData(), datosCliente.getLength(), datosCliente.getAddress(), datosCliente.getPort());


            String datosImport = new String( datosCliente.getData());
            System.out.println(datosImport);


       // else{
            String[] a = datosImport.split(" ");
            xS = a[0].substring(a[0].indexOf("=")+1, a[0].length());
            yS = a[1].substring(a[1].indexOf("=")+1, a[1].length());
            zS = a[2].substring(a[2].indexOf("=")+1, a[2].length());
            gradosS = a[3].substring(a[3].indexOf("=")+1, a[3].length());
            x = Double.parseDouble(xS);
            y = Double.parseDouble(yS);
            z = Double.parseDouble(zS);
            grados = Double.parseDouble(gradosS);

    }
     } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }



}
}
```

Comment: parece que intentas parsear un número que tiene más de un punto, algo así: 2.0.1, con lo cual no es capaz de pasarlo a Float y te da ese error

Comment: Pon el código completo

Comment: Como dice @PabloSimonDiEstefano, el error es porque estás recibiendo un dato que tratas de convertir a un valor numérico y no es posible ya que el literal tiene dos(o mas) puntos. Pon tu código en un `try/catch` y decide que hacer en esos casos.

Comment: Sí, acabo de actualizar con lo último que recibo (que tiene 2 puntos), no entiendo porque de repente "aparecen" 2 puntos si antes no estaban apareciendo

Comment: Bueno, puedes contar los puntos que aparecen en tu cadena `gradosS`: `int count = StringUtils.countMatches(gradosS, ".");` y usar replace para quitar el ultimo por ejemplo

Comment: Muchas gracias @Pikoh, probaré eso, pero ¿cual puede ser la razón de que aparezca de repente ese punto?

Comment: Eso es imposible que podamos decirtelo, ya que no sabemos de donde estás leyendo los datos ni su protocolo :)

Comment: Pffff que pu**** entonces, muchas gracias de nuevo :)

Comment: Aunque la solución de @Pikoh resuelva *parcialmente* el problema, debes buscar **el motivo** por el que los datos no están bajo tu control, haciendo lo que les da la real gana (esa es quizá la mayor responsabilidad de un programador: conocer y controlar sus datos).  ¿Qué tal si hay un virus o hacker que modifica los datos? ¿Que tal si se modifican datos de forma *valida* sin que lo sepas y en una app de un banco alguien se ingresa más dinero del real? Haciendo este comentario, quiero evitar que pases algunos años en la cárcel, porque si eres el responsable del sistema, lo eres de los datos.

Comment: `grados=0.0.0` deberías revisar el servidor que genera los datos, en lugar de intentar corregir algo asi se deberia rechazar.

Comment: Creo que ya se porque es, estoy leyendo los datos del Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION y mi móvil no puede leer ese sensor, por lo que envía ceros, y puede que debido a eso se "cuele" ese punto, otra cosa no se me ocurre